# AWS:elastic_ip Assign a name to an elastic ip using cloudformation

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I am trying to use cloudformation and assign a "name" to an elastic ip using the normal process i.e:

```
  IPAddress:
    Description: 'ip:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::StackName} - elastic up for something'
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::EIP'
    Properties:
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub 'ec2:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::StackName}'
```

For some reason cloudformation throws an error: "tags not supported", so I guess I am asking, is there a way to set the "Name" of the elastic ip with cloud-formation?

Cheers

Comment: Feature request: https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/aws-cloudformation-coverage-roadmap/issues/84

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Reason for your error is in CloudFormation, elastic IP resources "AWS::EC2::EIP" not supporting Tags for Properties.

For the second question, as far as I know, there's no way, **at the moment** to name an elastic IP from cloud formation.

Update (11/22/2019)
Tags are now supported. Refer the Docs [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-eip.html).

Comment: I was hoping that would not be the answer, but damn thats sucks.

Comment: So this is a problem with the CloudFormation Service? Because you can add tags to EIPs in the console. What's weird is AWS Config still doesn't see the tags.

Comment: Not sure when they added it, but as of 2021-06-01, Tags are supported as shown, so this is no longer a problem!

Answer (score 5):

Don't hold your breath, here is a [thread](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=96348) on AWS forums, started in 2012 on this subject.

Instead use [CloudFormation Custom Resources](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources-lambda.html) to varnish over this and other CFN shortcomings.

Following is my implementation using Python and boto3.

> Python source code for `tag-ec2-resource.py`

```
import cfnresponse
import boto3
import os


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print(event, context)
    ec2 = boto3.client('ec2', region_name=os.environ['AWS_REGION'])
    ResourceId = event['ResourceProperties']['ResourceId']
    TagKey = event['ResourceProperties']['TagKey']
    TagValue = event['ResourceProperties']['TagValue']
    responseData = {}

    if event['RequestType'] == 'Delete':
        try:
            response = ec2.delete_tags(
                Resources=[
                    ResourceId,
                ],
                Tags=[
                    {
                        'Key': TagKey,
                        'Value': TagValue
                    }
                ]
            )
            print(response)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

        cfnresponse.send(event, context, cfnresponse.SUCCESS, responseData, physicalResourceId=ResourceId)
        return

    if event['RequestType'] == 'Update':
        try:
            OldResourceId = event['OldResourceProperties']['ResourceId']
            OldTagKey = event['OldResourceProperties']['TagKey']
            OldTagValue = event['OldResourceProperties']['TagValue']
            response = ec2.delete_tags(
                Resources=[
                    OldResourceId,
                ],
                Tags=[
                    {
                        'Key': OldTagKey,
                        'Value': OldTagValue
                    }
                ]
            )
            print(response)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

    try:
        response = ec2.create_tags(
            Resources=[
                ResourceId,
            ],
            Tags=[
                {
                    'Key': TagKey,
                    'Value': TagValue
                },
            ]
        )
        print(response)
    except:
        pass

    cfnresponse.send(event, context, cfnresponse.SUCCESS, responseData, physicalResourceId=ResourceId)
```

(you'll need to package [cfn-response](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-lambda-function-code.html#cfn-lambda-function-code-cfnresponsemodule) with this function)

> define Lambda role

```
  TagEC2ResourceLambdaRole:
    Type: 'AWS::IAM::Role'
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Service:
            - 'lambda.amazonaws.com'
          Action:
          - 'sts:AssumeRole'
      Path: '/'
      Policies:
      - PolicyName: 'AmazonLambdaServicePolicy'
        PolicyDocument:
          Version: '2012-10-17'
          Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action:
            - 'logs:CreateLogGroup'
            - 'logs:CreateLogStream'
            - 'logs:PutLogEvents'
            - 'ec2:Describe*'
            - 'ec2:CreateTags'
            - 'ec2:DeleteTags'
            Resource: '*'
```

> define Lambda function

```
  TagEC2ResourceLambda:
    Type: 'AWS::Lambda::Function'
    Properties:
      FunctionName: !Join [ '-', [ 'tag-ec2-resource', !Select [ 2, !Split [ '/', !Ref 'AWS::StackId' ]]]]
      Handler: 'tag-ec2-resource.lambda_handler'
      Code:
        S3Bucket: !Ref 'S3Bucket'
        S3Key: !Sub 'lambda-functions/tag-ec2-resource-${LambdaVersion}.zip'
      Runtime: python2.7
      Role: !Ref 'TagEC2ResourceLambdaRoleArn'
      Description: 'Tag EC2 resource.'
      Timeout: 30
      Tags:
      - Key: Name
        Value: !Ref 'NameTag'
```

> Lastly, tag EIP using custom resource in your template

```
  MyEipTag:
    Type: 'Custom::TagEC2Resource'
    Properties:
      ServiceToken: !Sub 'arn:${AWS::Partition}:lambda:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:function:tag-ec2-resource-${LambdaStackGuid}'
      ResourceId: !GetAtt MyEiP.AllocationId
      TagKey: 'Name'
      TagValue: 'my-very-special-EIP'
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Super cool @ab77! Though a sadly complicated option to achieve what CF ought to make simple :-(

Comment: I've published all the code here: https://github.com/ab77/cfn-generic-custom-resource

Comment: After holding my breath for 9 years(!?), I can breathe again!  Not sure when they added it, but as of 2021-06-01, Tags are supported as shown, so this is no longer a problem!